# How to set the same destination folder with For loop variables?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to convert all my .avi videos in `.mkv` format, and to do so I found a good script, that I re-managed to be useful in my case.
My structure is something like that:

- Mainfolder

  - folder1
  - folder2
  - folder3

So, I copy the batch file with this code in the Mainfolder and it converts all the files in the subfolders. And this is the code:

```
for /R %%Z in ("*.avi") do mkvmerge.exe -o "%%~nZ.mkv" "%%~Z"
```

The only problem is that this is converting the files in the Mainfolder instead of the sub-folders where the videos are. This is of course quite annoying cause I have to move all the files in their folders after the conversion.

So my questions to you are:

1. How can I write the code to get the output in the same folders as the input?
2. What is the meaning of `~n` and why is right there in the code?

Answer (score 0):

So, what's happen if you try:

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" & setlocal
for /r /d %%i in (*)do if exist "%%~fi\*.avi" for /f tokens^=* %%I in (
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~i:*.avi"')do echo\mkvmerge.exe -o "%%~dpnI.mkv" "%%~dpnxI"

endlocal & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & goto :EOF
```

If the output seems to work to you, remove **`echo\`**:

```all-bat
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~i:*.avi"')do echo\mkvmerge.exe -o "%%~dpnI.mkv" "%%~dpnxI"
```